# MySQL Replication: Preventing master server from replicating table inserts

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a logging table on the master server that is inserted into very often. I don't need this table replicated to the slave servers, and in fact I already have replicate-ignore-table set on the slaves to ignore it.

However, that only happens after all of those inserts are fetched from the master. I'd like to prevent those inserts from getting sent to the slaves entirely for 2 reasons:

1. Cut down on network traffic between the servers
2. I've had cases of the relay log entries being corrupted (and having to skip corrupted entries). Given the quantity of inserts into the logging table, it's always on those inserts (which aren't necessary anyway).

Is it possible to somehow prevent the master from sending back the logs for a specific table? Or, prevent the inserts from showing up in the master's bin-log files? I'm only aware of ignoring databases in the master's bin-log files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, send "SET SESSION sql_log_bin=0" to MySQL before inserting a logging row. Then set it back to 1 afterward.

This approach gives you fine-grained control over when and when not to binary-log. Only possible drawback is that the database user will need the SUPER privilege.